# Attempt to de-reference a null when try to save button click this error trigger fire

Tags: apex

```
Requirement : ChangingFirstlttrUpper 

Trigger 
--------
trigger ChangingFirstlttrUpper on Account (before insert,before update) {
   ChanignToCaps.Change(trigger.new);
      if(trigger.isBefore )
         if(trigger.IsInsert ||trigger.IsUpdate )
           ChanignToCaps.Change(trigger.new);
}

handler helper class

global class ChanignToCaps{
   global static void Change( Project__c [] Pro){
      for(Project__c  P :Pro){
         if(P.PoPupfield__c !=null || P.PoPupfield__c  != ' '){
           P.PoPupfield__c = formatToUpper(P.PoPupfield__c );
   }
   
}
handler helper class
public class FirstlttrUpper{
public static String formatToUpper (String Str) {
String result = '';
for (String iter : Str.split('[ ]+')) {
   if (iter != null && iter != '') {
    if (iter.length() > 1) {
     result += iter.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + iter.substring(1,iter.length()) + ' ';
    }
    else
     result += iter.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + ' ';
   }
}
return result;
}
}
```

ERROR!
ChangingFirstlttrUpper: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.FirstlttrUpper.formatToUpper: line 4, column 1 Class.ChanignToCaps.Change: line 10, column 1 Trigger.ChangingFirstlttrUpper: line 2, column 1

Answer (score 0):

This line on the helper class here stands out:

```
if(P.PoPupfield__c !=null || P.PoPupfield__c  != ' ')
```

That `if` condition will *always* evaluate to `true`, even if there is a `null` value in the field. It looks like the error is pointing to a `null` value being fed into the parameter for `formatToUpper`.

To fix that, I would recommend the following:

```
if(P.PoPupfield__c !=null && P.PoPupfield__c  != ' ')
```

If that's not it, can you provide some data from the record you tried to save?